# Custom Icon not refreshing ( e.g.: read aloud icon )

Tags: google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

i just updated on my google glass app the custom icon for the Read Aloud but the app ( it is a Python + GAE ) still delivers the old version to the devices.

Am i missing something here?

KR

Comment: Have you promoted the new version to default. In addition all static resources will be probably be cached all over the place.

Comment: Yes, if i check the card in the G playground i can see the new icon. Not on the glass tho.

Comment: Try sticking something like ?x=x at the end of the URL. If you get the new image you know it's being cached somewhere.  This means you will need to use cache busting techniques or wait for caches to expire